# Need to restart SharePoint Database Server, What to do?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am planning to restart SharePoint Database server. Can anybody suggest what action I should take before and after restarting SharePoint Database server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a clean and safe approach, shut down the SharePoint servers first.
If you are running search, pause all crawls or let them finish first before shutting down the SharePoint servers, restart SQL then bring the SharePoint servers back up.

- Keep an eye on the ULS logs for a few minutes while you see everything re-attach and check for any error notifications.
- Check the windows logs for any major errors.
- Check on the Timer jobs in central admin for failing jobs
- Start the search crawls again
- Navigate to each web application in a browser to warm it back up before your users get back online.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. Just restart your SQL Server. SharePoint will reconnect when the SQL Server service is available/databases are online. Obviously check that the SQL Server starts up correctly and all of your databases do come online, but at that point you can just test Central Administration, your Web Applications, etc.